# Как создать таблицу в базе данных? (PHP+MySQL)

Tags: mysql, база-данных, php, sql

Здравствуйте!

Нашел в Интернете видео уроки по курсу `Apache+PHP+MySQL`, но там все действия происходят, как я понял, в Украине, хотя рассказывает на русском. Рассказали как и привели код по созданию базы данных и таблиц в ней.

Создание таблицы в базе данных `Usersbd`:

```
<?php
$Link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345');

if(!$Link) echo "Не удалось подключится к серверу";
else
{
    mysql_select_db('Usersbd');

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE 'Users'  ('UserID'  VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_ukrainian_ci NOT NULL ". 
        " 'Name'  VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_ukrainian_ci, ". 
        " 'E-mail'  VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_ukrainian_ci)";
    if (mysql_query($sql))
        echo "Создание таблицы завершено";
    else
        echo "Таблицу создать не удалось";
}
?>
```

`character set cp1251` - поле поддерживает кириллическую кодировку
`collate cp1251_ukrainian_ci` - порядок сравнения кириллицы с поддержкой украинских символов
`not null` - поле не пустое

Так как я живу в России — мне не нужны украинские символы. Я попробовал убрать пункт сравнения, реакция была однозначной:  "Таблицу создать не удалось"...

Поискал ещё информацию по этому курсу, но ничего хорошего и понятного не нашел.. Скажите, как реализовать это для нашего региона, да и вообще? Спасибо.

После проделанных действий, по советам других участников получилось так:

```
<?php
$Link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '12345');

if(!$Link) echo "Не удалось подключится к серверу";
 else
{
   mysql_select_db('TestBD');

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE  `tests` (`id` INT NOT NULL ,`test` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ))";

if (mysql_query($sql))
    echo "Создание таблицы завершено";
  else
    echo "Таблицу создать не удалось";
}
?>
```

Но все равно ничего не работает, и таблицу не создает...

Comment: Извиняюсь, но если Вы смотрите видео-уроки на тему "как создать таблицу в БД", то скорее всего Вы понятия не имеете что это и как оно устроено.
Советую Вам для начала погуглить на тему "что такое базы данных", а потом зайти на сайт mysql.com и почитать документацию по созданию таблиц в БД.
А раз уж Вы изучаете пых, то не мешало бы пойти на сайт php.net и воспользоваться их поиском со словами "mysql_connect", там куча информации. И еще один совет: попробуйте в консоли (если под виндами, то cmd), зайти в сам мускуль, и выполнить те самые команды подряд, получите много интересного. Удачи! :)

Comment: @Alex Silaev, дело в то, что как раз с базами данных я то знаком)Перед новым годом защищал курсовую, по дисциплине "Управление данными", ее содержимое можете посмотреть здесь http://www.twirpx.com/file/330227/ ) А спрашивал я работу php и mysql, т.е работа с БД через них)

Comment: Курсовые - это все фигня :) Тогда идите на php.net с поиском "mysql_connect", должно помочь :)

Comment: А база существует?

Comment: Ваш курсовик был по FoxPro, а сейчас пытаетесь изучить Mysql. 
Синтаксис SQL у них несколько различается. Поэтому чтобы не тратить кучу времени на изучение, просто установите PhpMyAdmin.
Там вы сможете визуально создать таблицу и на выходе получить уже готовый SQL. А уже где потом этот SQL использовать, через mysql_query(); или еще как, это уже не суть важно.

Comment: А если бы действия происходили в Калифорнии, то суть от этого поменялась бы?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE  `testdb`.`tests` (`id` INT NOT NULL ,`test` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ));
```

вот например в обычной кодировке  utf-8

Comment: Спасибо!) Попробую;)

Comment: alexeyxo, я сделал по вашему совету, но ничего не работает, пишет "Внутрення ошибка сервера".. Хотя БД TestBD он создал... Что делать?(

Answer (score 5):

Лучше не используйте cp1251, utf удобнее. Заменяйте `cp1251` на `utf8` и `cp1251_ukrainian_ci` на `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
   $Link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123456');

   if(!$Link) echo "Не удалось подключится к серверу";
   else
   {
      mysql_select_db('Usersbd');

      $sql = "CREATE TABLE `Userbd`.`Users` (`id` INT( 3 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,`name` VARCHAR( 25 ) CHARACTER SET

      utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL ,`passwd` VARCHAR( 10 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL) ENGINE = MYISAM";
      if (mysql_query($sql))
         echo "Создание таблицы завершено";
      else
         echo "таблица не создана";
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала выведите ошибку, скорей всего ошибка в синтаксисе.

```
if (mysql_query($sql))
    echo "Создание таблицы завершено";
  else
    echo mysql_error();
```

или даже так:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

и насчет PhpMyAdmin, народ правильно говорит, установите его. Практически все программисты баз данных используют конструкторы.

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень отличное решение всех проблем с базой данных.
Скачиваешь [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) заливаешь на свой сервер, предварительно вбив в файл config.default данные для доступа к БД и катаешься по всем своим таблицам как сыр в масле. А если тебе нужен текст обращения к БД, при создании таблицы через [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) ты всегда его можешь посмотреть, скопировать и использовать его как тебе вздумается.
Также огромный плюс [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) - то, что ты можешь всегда без проблем сделать резервную копию всей базы данных, и переносить на любую машину.

Comment: Мне кажется, суть не в том, чтобы таблица появилась. Суть в самом процессе создания. «Понимание», понимаете?

Comment: Понимаю, Так я и говорю что в phpMyAdmin можно посмотреть абсолютно любой текст обращения к БД. Набрал там табличку которая тебе нужна, нажал на кнопку и смотришь на текст mySQL. в нем можно легко и быстро разобраться, что то вырезать, что то изменить и вставить куда нужно.

Comment: Это всё от лукавого. Если не знаешь, как сделать руками, то никакой phpMyAdmin не поможет. Потому что его функционал ограничен. Потому что он делает самым эффективным способом. Ну и т.д. и т.п.. Едва ли существует программа, реализующая 100% возможностей SQL.

Comment: По моему вопрос не стоял про все возможности SQL. Вопрос был создать таблицу, собственно как это сделать и какой текст для этого нужен я ответил. А вопроса типа "создать базу данных для пентагона.." не было и поэтому за 100% возможностей SQL я не отвечал.

Comment: Уже лет 8 использую PhpMyAdmin. Все удобно и понятно там. 
Создал таблицу, сделал экспорт -> только структура.
и получил на выходе SQL, который создает таблицу. 
Это экономит массу времени.

Answer (score 0):

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE 'Users'  ('UserID'  VARCHAR(5) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_ukrainian_ci NOT NULL ". 
    " 'Name'  VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_ukrainian_ci, ". 
    " 'E-mail'  VARCHAR(25) CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_ukrainian_ci)";
$result_query = mysql_query($sql); // теперь будет выполняться
if ($result_query) { // условный оператор проверяет выполнилось ли
    echo "Создание таблицы завершено";
} else { echo "Таблицу создать не удалось"; }
```